# ServiceStack Cookie not setting in browser

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-bsd, servicestack-razor

I have an application with Razor Enabled and a service like this:

```cs
public object Post(SelectTerminalRequest request)
{
    var location = base.Request.AbsoluteUri.CombineWith(request.TerminalId, "/flights");
    if (Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("Terminal"))
    {
        Request.Cookies.Remove("Terminal");
    }
    Request.Cookies.Add("Terminal",
        new Cookie("Terminal", request.TerminalId.ToString()) 
            { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1) });
    return new HttpResult(HttpStatusCode.Redirect)
    {
        Location = location
    };
}
```

However, when I try and access that cookie in my Razor View, its empty:

```cs
@{
     Cookie cookie;
     Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("Terminal", out cookie);
     var baseUri = Request.GetApplicationUrl() + "/terminals";
     var redirectUrl = cookie != null ? baseUri + "/" + cookie.Value + "/flights" : baseUri;
 }
```

When I browse my cookies, I don't see anything with `Terminal`:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll kick yourself for this one, I am sure, but adding cookies should be on the `Response`, you used the `Request` object. :) Don't worry I've done that too!

```cs
Response.SetCookie("Terminal", request.TerminalId.ToString());
```